# QSound doesn't work in if statement

Tags: qt, qt5

This doesn't work:

```
QString directory  = "";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QString boo = getDir();

    if(!boo.isEmpty()) {

       directory = boo;

       QSound s1(directory);
       QApplication a(argc, argv);
       MainWindow w;
       s1.play();
      // MainWindow shows fine but QSound doesnt work at all
    } else {
        //somethingelse
    }
}
```

But this works fine.

```
QString directory  = "";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString boo = getDir();

    if(!boo.isEmpty()) {

        directory = boo;

        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;


    } else {
        //somethingelse
    }

    QSound s1(directory);
    s1.play();
}
```

The question is - What's wrong with my first example? i have no idea to be honest.

I tried many times and it still doesn't work. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: Try initializing QSound after you initialize QApplication & MainWindow

Comment: I'm surprised that either works without a call to QApplication::exec, as I would have expected the main thread's event loop would be required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is simply, your QSound instance goes out of scope and gets destructed at the end of "then" block, and sound stops playing before you hear anything.

Move the definition out of the "then" block, before it. Then just start playing it in "then" block.